# Bootstrap CSS breaks when logged in with Devise

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

This is going to be quite lengthy.

Here is my _home.html.erb partial that I want rendered when users are not signed in.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to Stynyl</h1>
    <p>...where style meets vinyl</p>
    <% if !user_signed_in? %>
     <%= link_to 'Log in', new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
      <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path, class: 'btn btn-lg btn-default' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the index of all Things. It is also my root. Note the first line:

```
<%= render 'pages/home' if !user_signed_in? %>

<div id="things" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @things.each do |thing| %>
    <div class='panel panel default'>
    <div class="box">
      <%= link_to image_tag(thing.image.url(:medium)), thing %>
      <div class='panel-body'>
      <strong><p><%= thing.title %></p></strong>
      <p><%= thing.description %></p>
      <%= thing.user.email %>

      <% if thing.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to edit_thing_path(thing) do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to thing_path(thing), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
      <% end %>
      </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

What's happening is that when a user is signed in, my Things display properly on the home page. However, when signed out, the Things scatter across the page, even outside of the container div I have placed them in. Here is the GitHub repository for the project:

https://github.com/drichards2013/stynyl

I've left it here because you will probably need to have a look at it to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two divs inside link_to tag. Corrected Code

```
<%= render 'pages/home' if !user_signed_in? %>

<div id="things" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @things.each do |thing| %>
    <div class='panel panel default'>
    <div class="box">
      <%= link_to image_tag(thing.image.url(:medium)), thing %>
      <div class='panel-body'>
      <strong><p><%= thing.title %></p></strong>
      <p><%= thing.description %></p>
      <%= thing.user.email %>

      <% if thing.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to edit_thing_path(thing) do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to thing_path(thing), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks, pal.